# PHP help on declaring variables inside of a variable

Tags: php

Okay, so I have a page that calls a list of information from a msyql database.  say, i have a table called TABLE with columns id, name, phone numbers, and a radio button group (home,cell,work) etc. I've created a script that prints out in a table the name, phone number, and "status (not sure what best to call this, but it's the value of the radio buttons) the radio buttons.  What I would like to do is make it so that for each row, if i assign a value to the radio buttons, it will edit the status part. so say, on row 1, i click home, and row 2, cell, and row 3 home... and so forth, and i hit a submit button it will update the database.

So, this is my code for the radio button section in the table. This is under a php tag

What I ended up doing basically is calling each group of radio buttons, status_type1, status_type2, status_type3... basically radio name='status_type".$info['id']."

I want to do an if statement to see if there are values assigned from any clicks on the buttons, then submit them for entry. This is what I have so far.

```
//Radio Button Template
  <fieldset>
<input type='radio' id='status_type_home' name='status_type".$info['id']."' value='home'  />
    <label for='status_type_home'>home</label>
<input type='radio' id='status_type_work' name='status_type".$info['id']."' value='work'  />
    <label for='status_type_work'>work</label>
<input type='radio' id='status_type_cell' name='status_type".$info['id']."' value='cell'  />
    <label for='status_type_cell'>cell</label>
</fieldset>

 </td>";


//If statement to submit radio buttons

    if ($_POST['status_type "$info['id']"']) 
{
$edit_status_sql="UPDATE status SET type = 'status_type".$info['id'] . "' WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";

$edit_status_res=mysqli_query($connection, $edit_status_sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

The problem I have is basically, I've declared the name of the radio buttons as status_type[variable based on the id].  Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how i'm supposed to format it or if it's even possible to declare a variable within a variable.  Thanks!

Comment: do a var_dump($_POST);die; then you see the key value pairs

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is not syntactically correct. Assuming that `$info` has the correct values, it should read

```
if ($_POST["status_type$info[id]"])
```

Notice:

- The space was removed to match the HTML
- The double quotes were removed from inside the string and now delimit it instead
- The single quotes *within* the array index for `$info` were removed

You can also use the equivalent `$_POST["status_type".$info['id']]`.

However, there are also numerous other issues with that code:

- It appears that you are using the same HTML ids for multiple radio buttons in your page (ids are reused for each row). That is incorrect; ids should be unique.
- The `if` should prevent an `E_NOTICE` if the variable is not defined; i.e. it should read `if(isset($_POST[...]))`.
- The code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). This should be fixed **right now**.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
if ($_POST["status_type".$info['id'].""]){
    .....
}
```

you have:

```
  if ($_POST['status_type "$info['id']"']) {
    .....
  }
```

also i would do smth like this: `$statusType = "status_type".$info['id'];` and use it like `$_POST["$statusType"]`

AND

```
$edit_status_sql="UPDATE status SET type = '."$statusType".' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```